# Obtain date for prior month and prior year issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement that, for the most part was working for me, or so I thought.  I need to return the First Day of the Previous Month in a MM/DD/YYYY format.  Now that we're into a new year (January specifically) this isn't correct.

```
SELECT convert(char(10),DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getdate())-1, 0)),120) AS LastYearFirstOfPreviousMonth
```

If I use this with the 1st of Feb, on-wards it works great!

```
SELECT convert(char(10),DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, '2018-02-01')-1, 0)),120) AS LastYearFirstOfPreviousMonth
```

same if it was '2018-03-01', etc.  But when I use '2018-01-01', instead of getting '2017-12-01', I get '2016-12-01'.

Ex. Let's say getdate() brings back "07/12/2018", the date I need would be for the 1st of the previous month for the previous year. So it would be "06/01/2017". For "01/03/2018", it would be "12/01/2017". But my statement brings back "12/01/2016".

What's wrong with my logic?

SP excerpt below:

```
SELECT c.ClientID ... 
INTO PC_Benefits_Expired 
from Client_Program cp 
INNER JOIN .... 
WHERE (CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS DATE) 
--OR 
--FirstDayOfCurrentMonthPriorYear CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)) AS DATE)) 
--FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear and CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)) AS DATE) 
--LastDayOfCurrentMonthCurrentYear and CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE)='2017-02-28'
```

Comment: what's wrong with your logic is that your current result is correct. The previous year of 2018 is 2017, so now you are standing in January 2017, the previous month is December 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
```

This gets the last day from 2 months ago, then adds one day to it to give you the first day of one month ago.

You can format however you like:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)),'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

**Edit:**

For the clarified issue, you have two separate conditions.  I would just use a `CASE` statement to handle the January condition differently:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) = 1
            THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
            ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)))
       END AS LastYearFirstOfPreviousMonthDATEADD
```

Comment: How would I add this to my SP?

Comment: SELECT c.ClientID
...
INTO PC_Benefits_Expired
from Client_Program cp
INNER JOIN ....
WHERE  (CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS DATE) OR --FirstDayOfCurrentMonthPriorYear CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)) AS DATE)) --FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear  and CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)) AS DATE) --LastDayOfCurrentMonthCurrentYear  and  CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE)='2017-02-28'

Comment: @DataCrypt Your SP is a little confusing with the comments, but if I understand it right then you can copy paste the `CASE` statement above into your `WHERE` clause.  So.. `WHERE (CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= insert case statement here`

Comment: @DataCrypt Long story short, just put the `CASE` statement wherever you currently have your date logic for previous year, previous month.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getdate())-1,0),101)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the year to be -1 too which is where I'm stuck.  Let's say getdate() brings back "07/12/2018", the date I need would be for the 1st of the previous month for the previous year.  So it would be "06/01/2017".  For "01/03/2018", it would be "12/01/2017".  But my statement brings back "12/01/2016".  Yours is using the current year.

Comment: @DataCrypt because it doesn't really make sense...you need the previous month of the previous year...so your current result is correct

Comment: I'm using this in a query where I need to grab data for clients that have an enrollment within a certain Start and End date (normally the past year).  When the query/report is run, I use the current month and go back 1 year for their Start date (StartDate >= .FirstDayOfCurrentMonthPriorYear OR >= FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear).  The End date is <= the end of the current month/year (LastDayofCurrentMonthCurrentYear). I use the OR FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear to allow one extra month of data in case they didn't get to run their report that month.

Comment: my original SQL works, but just fails in January as I'm getting the last month (which I need and THEN taking away the year which I need.  Taking away the month in this case puts me back to the last year and then I'm still taking away another year which is messing it up.  It's like I need to determine if I'm in January and not do the DATEADD(year, -1,... in my initial post example.  I hope this makes sense.