# Using CASE in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error in my `WHERE` clause on the very last AND statement `AND CAST(cp.EndDate...)`.  I just added the CASE statement to know if the month is January and to compare the cp.startdate >= value1 OR value 2

Error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

My `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS DATE) 
    OR --FirstDayOfCurrentMonthPriorYear
    CASE 
       WHEN DATEPART(month,getdate()) = 1 --month is January
          THEN CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0) AS DATE) --FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear
          ELSE CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()) -1, 0)) AS DATE) --FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear
    END) 
    AND CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS DATE) --LastDayOfCurrentMonthCurrentYear
```

Not sure what's wrong... any help in implementing this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Then how may I add a local variable to my SP and set it to the result of this CASE statement and then use that variable in my WHERE clause?

Comment: An error message is quite obvious... `WHERE` statement have to contain a boolean expression. Your `CASE` statement does not return boolean value. Of course, you can use `CASE` in `WHERE` statement. See: [WHERE + CASE](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/06/18/write-case-statement-clause-interview-question-week-127/)

Comment: You have a case statement with no condition. So, your case statement evaluates to a value. But, what is the condition for the where clause? ie. What do you want your case result to =, like, <, > etc?

Comment: You want to return rows where a condition is true. Your first comparison, is A greater than or equal to B, will return true or false. But the CASE statement returns a date. I suspect that you actually want to compare startdate to the date that the CASE statement returns.

Comment: In other words, you can't say "where A >= B or C"; you must say "where A >= B or A >= C".

Comment: Also... I agree with others that putting a case statement in a where clause that is evaluating functions like getdate() is a pretty bad idea. Set a variable instead. Your question about how to use variables in SQL stored sprocs is a completely separate question from this one and I'm sure you'll find the answer on SO without asking a new question.

Comment: would be very helpful if we see actual data and full query. even using sqlfiddle

Comment: also: `CAST(DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month, 0, @dt)-1, 0) AS DATE)` evaluates to `--FirstDayOfLastMonth`, not `--FirstDayOfLastMonthPriorYear`

Comment: Explain what you want to do.  There is probably simpler logic.

Comment: @SQLCliff - correct it is FirstDayOfLastMonth and changed the wording - but it really is last year since last month was last year when we're in January.  This is why I had to add a SQL variable to my stored proc and assign it to the evaluation of this CASE statement.  When in January, get the FirstDayOfLastMonth using the DATEADD(month.. etc.) and when NOT in January get the FirstDayofLastMonthPriorYear using DATEADD(year,-1,).  Make sense? Thanks everyone for your feedback!  I believe I got it working with a SQL variable and then using that in my WHERE clause.

Comment: Previous question for those interested, a little extra background https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084154/obtain-date-for-prior-month-and-prior-year-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a pure syntax point of view, you need to compare something to your `CASE` output. Something like this would be syntactically correct.

```
WHERE 
(
    CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS DATE) 
    OR 
    CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >= CASE 
                                   WHEN DATEPART(month,getdate()) = 1 --month is January
                                      THEN CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0) AS DATE)
                                      ELSE CAST(DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()) -1, 0)) AS DATE)
                                    END 
)
    AND CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084154/obtain-date-for-prior-month-and-prior-year-issue)

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
WHERE CAST(cp.startdate AS DATE) >=  CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) = 1
                                          THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))
                                          ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)))
                                     END --FirstDayOfCurrentMonthPriorYear
AND CAST(cp.EndDate AS DATE) <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) --LastDayOfCurrentMonthCurrentYear
```

This checks that the `cp.startdate` is greater than or equal to the first day of the current month in the prior year, and that the `cp.enddate` is less than or equal to the last day of the current month.  Replace `GETDATE()` with your date of choice.